# How to top up Progress Bar for upload function

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, progress-bar, code-behind

I have already set one upload function like this
aspx

```
 <table width="100%" class="border" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="5" align="left">Upload</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <asp:Label ID="lblErrorUpload" runat="server" CssClass="errMsg" />
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="fUpload" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />
        </tr>
       </table>
```

aspx.cs

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("Temp")))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/UploadFile/Temp"));

    string sourceFileName = string.Format("{0}myfile.xlsx", Server.MapPath("~/UploadFile/Temp\\"));
    if (Path.GetExtension(fUpload.PostedFile.FileName) != ".xlsx")
    {
        lblErrorUpload.Text = "The extension is invalid, please upload with file with .xlsx";
    }
    else
    {
        fUpload.SaveAs(sourceFileName);
    }
}
```

just simple function. how can i top up the progress bar for this?

[image: no spinner]

Answer (score 0):

A Progress Bar like in c# is not possible with the standard tools.

Have a look at this project: https://spin.js.org/. When you click on the button a div is shown as long as the upload is processing.

**Short example of the project**

Insert into your aspx head section:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> //or any newer version
<script src="Scripts/spin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowProgress() {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var modal = $('<div />');
                modal.addClass("modal");
                $('body').append(modal);
                var loading = $(".loading");
                loading.show();
                var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
                var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
                loading.css({ top: top, left: left });
            }, 200);
        }
    </script>
```

Into the style section of your aspx head section:

```
.modal
    {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: black;
        z-index: 99;
        opacity: 0.8;
        filter: alpha(opacity=80);
        -moz-opacity: 0.8;
        min-height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .loading
    {
        font-family: Verdana;
        font-size: 10pt;
        color: Red;
        border: 5px solid #376a8f;
        width: 325px;
        height: 130px;
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        background-color: White;
        z-index: 999;
    }
```

In the bottom of your aspx body section:

```
 <div class="loading" align="center">
                <br
                    <span class="style9"><strong>Uploading, please wait</strong></span><br />

                    <div id="foo"></div> 
                </div>

                <script>
                    var opts = {
                        lines: 12, // The number of lines to draw
                        length: 7, // The length of each line
                        width: 5, // The line thickness
                        radius: 10, // The radius of the inner circle
                        corners: 1, // Corner roundness (0..1)
                        rotate: 0, // The rotation offset
                        direction: 1, // 1: clockwise, -1: counterclockwise
                        color: '#376a8f', // #rgb or #rrggbb or array of colors
                        speed: 1, // Rounds per second
                        trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
                        shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
                        hwaccel: false, // Whether to use hardware acceleration
                        className: 'spinner', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
                        zIndex: 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
                        top: '50%', // Top position relative to parent
                        left: '50%' // Left position relative to parent
                    };
                    var target = document.getElementById('foo');
                    var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
                </script>
```

Finaly add the `OnClientClick` to your `Button`:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="fUpload" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" OnClientClick="ShowProgress();return true;"/>
```

This shows a spining circle and the text while uploading the file. You can adjust the text and color and so on like descripted on the page.

Comment: so close, just my spinner is not coming out, i had added the css and js inside of it. i top up the screenshot from my question there.

Comment: Be sure that you have the correct path to the spin.js, for me it is stored in the Scripts folder `<script src="Scripts/spin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: I had put to my js folder and refers it as js/spin.js but it is still not working, then i am still finding how exactly import the js

Comment: Have you also put the jquery js file in the folder and your code?

Comment: yep i put to my folder then refers like other script in my .aspx, i also tried to put it from the top row of the scripts or lowest place from the scripts, neither way is working